# Difference in string when passing a carriage return

Tags: go

In Go, I run the application from the command line as follows:

```
myapp -message "FOK \nHost:"
```

In my code:

```
var args = os.Args
var command = args[1]
var message= args[2]
```

the message will have the value "FOK \nHost:". Printing the value of message gives me:

```
fmt.Println("message-> " + message)
```

output

```
message-> FOK \nHost:
```

[image]

but if I set the value of the message in the application using the same value, the output is different.

```
 message = "FOK \nHost:"
```

output

```
 message mod-> FOK
 Host:
```

[image]

I'm trying to accomplish the second result, so I'm trying to figure out why are the arguments string different thane when I assign it in the code.

Comment: You're not passing a carriage return (or a newline, carriage return is `\r`), you are passing the literal characters `\ `and `n`.

Comment: How would I pass a carriage return and not the literal \ and n?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/dIJS54bPfV6 try replace (note old argument is a raw string [backquotes], the new argument is an interpreted string [doublequotes])

Comment: By quoting it and actually pressing the `return` key? (you are going to get a newline, not a plain carriage return). You need to decide if you want to accept the literal string exactly as required, or you want to parse any escaped `\r` or `\n` pairs.

Comment: Or use a different shell. You're likely using bash - try the same with zsh and it will work

Comment: Its actually a Windows command.  Unfortunately, I'm handing the application to others and will not have control over shell.